# Trouble with summing specific rows and columns

Tags: r, automation, sum

I have a problem and was wondering if there was a code that would let me solve my problem faster than doing it manually.

So for my example, I have 100 different funds with numerous securities in the fund. Within each fund, I have the `Name` of each type of security in the fund, the `Date` which shows the given quarter, the `State` where the security is issued, and the `Weighting` of each security of the total fund. The `Name` is not important, just the `State` from where it was issued is.

I was wondering if there was a way that would allow me to add up the `Weighting` from each different fund based on the specific `State` I want for each quarter. So let's say from Fund1, I need the sum of the `Weighting` just for the state SC and AZ in 16-1Q. The sum would be (.18 + .001). I do not need to include the weighting for KS because I am not interested in that specific state. I would only be interested in the states SC and AZ for every FundId. However, in my real problem I am interested in ~30 states. I would then do the same task for Fund1 for 16-2Q and so on until 17-4Q. My end goal is to find the sum of every portfolio weighting for the states I'm interested in and see how it changes over time. I can do this manually by each fund, but is there a way to automatically sum up the `Weighing` for each `FundId` based on the `State` I want and for each `Date` (16-1Q, 16-2Q, etc.)?

In the end I would like a table such as:

[image]

(.XX) is the sum of portfolio weight

[image]

Example of Data

Comment: To improve your chances of getting a good answer you should make it easier for the readers to understand and reproduce your issue. 1) Please share data needed to reproduce your scenario. `dput()` is a function in R that creates code to recreate your data. Use it on your data and paste the output into your question, to share the data with us. 2) Share code of attempts of solving the issue yourself. 3) Embed pictures into the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Example of Data link you sent has a much better data format than the "XX is the sum of portfolio weight" example... only in Excel would you prefer this other kind of format

so using the Example data frame, do this operation

```
library(dplyr)

example_data <- example_data %>%
group_by(Fund_Id) %>%
summarize(sum = sum(Weighting))
```

Comment: or maybe you want to group_by(State) or group_by(State, Fund_Id) both

Comment: Thank you! However, I only want to sum the Weighting for specific states I am interested in. How would I isolate the certain states in the code you wrote? (For example I just want to isolate AZ and SC)

Comment: example_data <- example_data %>%
   filter(State == "Florida") %>%
   group_by(Fund_Id) %>%
   summarize(sum = sum(Weighting))

this is a very common sort of workflow

Comment: hit the up arrow if this was helpful i'm trying to get out of a question ban I don't know why stackoverflow gave me a question ban it's super lame

Comment: I gotchu. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate` in `base R`

```
aggregate(Weighting ~ Fund_id, example_data, sum)
```